# Compiling QGIS with GRASS on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, ubuntu, compilation

I am on Ubuntu building QGIS with GRASS plugin. I have build GRASS code separately and used --prefix to provide the path

`GRASS_PREFIX` is `/usr/local/grass-6.4.2` and `GRASS_INCLUDE_DIR` is `/usr/local/grass-6.4.2/include` and `LIB_PATH` is `/usr/local/grass-6.4.2/lib/libgrass_gproj.so`. I have unchecked  WITH_GRASS

When I compile QGIS I get the following

```
[  0%] Built target version
[ 17%] Built target qgis_core
[ 19%] Built target qgis_analysis
[ 19%] Built target qgis_networkanalysis
[ 27%] Built target ui
[ 40%] Built target qgis_gui
[ 40%] Built target memoryprovider
[ 41%] Built target delimitedtextprovider
[ 42%] Built target osmprovider
[ 43%] Built target qgissqlanyconnection
[ 44%] Built target sqlanywhereprovider
[ 44%] Built target gdalprovider
[ 45%] Built target mssqlprovider
[ 47%] Built target postgresprovider
[ 48%] Built target spatialiteprovider
[ 48%] Built target crssync
[ 73%] Built target qgis
[ 75%] Built target diagramoverlay
[ 76%] Built target interpolationplugin
[ 76%] Built target dxf2shpconverterplugin
[ 77%] Built target spatialqueryplugin
[ 78%] Built target sqlanywhereplugin
[ 79%] Built target roadgraphplugin
[ 80%] Built target zonalstatisticsplugin
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassplugin.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lqgisgrass
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [output/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassplugin.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/plugins/grass/CMakeFiles/grassplugin.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What am I missing?

---

I solved it. I can see the GRASS plugin in QGIS but the plugin is not able to find the GRASS utilities.
Then I tried to build using `WITH_GRASS = yes`; to link the grassplugin to grass, then I get the following. I think it says there is a build directory issue.

How do I fix it?

```
Found GRASS: /usr/lib/grass64 (6.4.2)
Touch support disabled
Found Proj: /usr/lib/libproj.so
Found GEOS: /usr/lib/libgeos_c.so
Found GDAL: /usr/lib/libgdal.so (1.9.1)
Found Expat: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so
Found Spatialindex: /usr/lib/libspatialindex.so
Found Qwt: /usr/lib/libqwt-qt4.so (5.2.2)
Found Sqlite3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so
Found SpatiaLite: /usr/lib/libspatialite.so
Pedantic compiler settings enabled
Debug output enabled
Found Python executable: /usr/bin/python
Found Python version: 2.7.3
Found Python library: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
Found SIP version: 4.13.2
Found PyQt4 version: 4.9.1
CMake Error at src/plugins/grass/CMakeLists.txt:116 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  add_library cannot create target "grassplugin" because another target with
  the same name already exists.  The existing target is a module library
  created in source directory
  "/home/develop1/QGIS_Develop/qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/grass".  See
  documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.


CMake Error at src/plugins/grass/CMakeLists.txt:140 (TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES):
  Attempt to add link library "qgisgrass" to target "grassplugin" which is
  not built in this directory.


CMake Error at src/plugins/grass/CMakeLists.txt:140 (TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES):
  Attempt to add link library "qgis_gui" to target "grassplugin" which is not
  built in this directory.


CMake Error at src/plugins/grass/CMakeLists.txt:140 (TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES):
  Attempt to add link library "util" to target "grassplugin" which is not
  built in this directory.


CMake Error at src/plugins/grass/CMakeLists.txt:150 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
  add_executable cannot create target "qgis.g.browser" because another target
  with the same name already exists.  The existing target is an executable
  created in source directory
  "/home/develop1/QGIS_Develop/qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/grass".  See
  documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.


CMake Error at src/plugins/grass/CMakeLists.txt:152 (TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES):
  Attempt to add link library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so" to
  target "qgis.g.browser" which is not built in this directory.


CMake Error at src/plugins/grass/CMakeLists.txt:152 (TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES):
  Attempt to add link library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so" to
  target "qgis.g.browser" which is not built in this directory.


CMake Error at src/plugins/grass/CMakeLists.txt:160 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given target "grassplugin" which does not exist in this
  directory.


CMake Error at src/plugins/grass/CMakeLists.txt:172 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given target "qgis.g.browser" which does not exist in this
  directory.
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a special reason (you are customizing the code for instance), you should use the [UbuntuGIS repository](http://trac.osgeo.org/ubuntugis/wiki/UbuntuGISRepository).

The [10.04 LTS Lucid](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntugis/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=lucid) repository section is loaded with stable GIS tools including QGIS, GRASS, GDAL 1.9.2, Spatialite and PostGIS.  The [12.04 LTS Precise](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntugis/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=precise) section has nearly as much available and prebuilt, ready to run. More information is available at [UbuntuGIS page in Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGIS)

Someone else may be able to answer your compiling/building questions.

Answer (score 2):

To compile [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/) from source, including access to [GRASS-GIS' (version 6.4) modules](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/full_index.html), a working GRASS-GIS installation is required. GRASS-GIS can be installed within Ubuntu in various ways, for example

- by using pre-compiled binaries from the [UbuntuGIS repository](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ppa/) (details to be found in Ubuntu's respective [UbuntuGIS wiki-page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGIS))
- by compiling every dependency and GRASS-GIS itself from their sources (step-by-step documentation in the [Ubuntu dedicated GRASS-wiki page](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_Install_Ubuntu))

**Note,** most likely an appropriate entry in the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file (or in a dedicated file inside `ld.so.conf.d/` directory, customarily named with an `.conf` extension) will be necessary so a runnning QuantumGIS can detect the QGIS-GRASS plugin `libqgisgrass.so`. The entry might be like `/geo/osgeo/src/grass64_release/dist.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib` or similar -- it should point to GRASS librairies!

Having GRASS-GIS running on a system, QGIS can be compiled from source as documented in the  [INSTALL](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Building_QGIS_from_Source) file included in QGIS' source code repository. In short, given that pre-required build tools and package dependencies are installed and functional, the steps are:

- getting the latest source code, using for example git

```
git clone git://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS.git
```

- or downloading a compressed package of the latest stable version (as of this answer's date 1.8) using `wget` and  decompress it

```
wget http://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-1.8.0.tar.bz2
tar xvzf qgis_1.1.0.tar.gz
```

- enter (or create inside the QGIS source code directory) the directory where the compilation will take place and run the `ccmake` configuration tool

```
cd QuantumGIS
mkdir build
cd build
ccmake ..
```

At this point, don't forget to define the `GRASS_PREFIX` parameter, i.e. set it to the directory that holds GRASS-GIS' in your system (might be `/usr/lib/grass64` or even `/some/directory/grass64_release/dist.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` in case you don't install GRASS-GIS system/user-wide)

*Micha Silver* recommends in [a relevant blog-post, titled *Compiling QGIS on Fedora 10*](http://www.surfaces.co.il/?p=340), to check the configuration before compiling by instructing `ccmake -L`. If no errors are encountered, go trough the actual compilation using `make` (note, **without** `sudo`). In case of errors (e.g. untraceable librairies) go through the respective manuals, fora and public mailiing lists. The installation can be completed then simply by executing `sudo make install`.