# How to enable GRASS-modules in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-plugins, tools, configuration

I have the latest QuantumGIS-1.9.0-master from [Github](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS) with python-modules support and full GRASS-integration (GRASS-4.6.3-RC2) on Linux.

When opening the GRASS-tools plugin, it only displays six tools. But there are more like [300 installed](https://gist.github.com/4433623).

[image: Only six tools available?]

The QGIS-Wiki [tells me](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Adding_New_Tools_to_the_GRASS_Toolbox) to add *new tools to the GRASS toolbox* menu using some xml file in:

```
qgis/src/plugins/grass/config/default.qgc
```

But where to find this file and how to update it? Isn't the `src`-directory only used prior compiling QGIS?

And why are my GRASS modules not included in QGIS by default?

**Update 1**: Ok, at least I found the file:

```
~ $ find / -name default.qgc 2> /dev/null
/usr/local/share/qgis/grass/config/default.qgc
```

But the [contents look good](https://gist.github.com/4433686). How to trigger QGIS to load the tools? What's the point I'm missing here?

**Update 2**: Okay, using Sextante-plugin seems the way to go. But this is pretty much broken. I keep getting Error-Messages like [this one](https://gist.github.com/4434816). I tried reinstalling, but this didn't solve it.

[image: Sextante: broken all over.]

Comment: why not use the SEXTANTE toolbox? It also comes with support of GRASS toolsets

Comment: SEXTANTE is pretty broken. i can't figure out why. see update #2.

Comment: well, the error says that you didn't install sextante, respectively it could'nt find the path of your sextante plugin. Reinstall it and check if the options (Menu Analysis) are correct. Grass should also be installed. I am using the latest development version on Debian and it runs just fine :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, full installation of OSGeo4W:
http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/
Use the binary package(#1 under step 2).

Second, fetch the Sextante plugin for QGIS, and add it.

You should now be able to access the GRASS modules(I have currently 154 geoalgorithms).

Source:  I used this over the weekend to perform various raster analysis operations, most of which using GRASS-specific tools, all done within QGIS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't mention I'm using Linux operating system. Do I really need the full OSGeo package? I have installed: qgis-1.9.0-dev, grass-6.4.3-rc2, gdal/ogr, geos-3.2.2, proj-4.7.0, graphviz-2.26.3-r4, spatialindex-1.8.0 and spatialite-4.0.0 as described here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/45012/13692

Comment: Nevermind, after reboot it's working now. Sextante does exactly what I wanted to do! Thanks Bryce and @Curlew.